# Необходимо вычесть процент от финансовой величины

Tags: java, математика

необходимо вычесть процент от финансовой величины, которая сохранена в int (эффектив джава, стр. 303) , будет ли хорошей идеей этот процент вводить в float и производить вычисление result = finVal - (finVal * procent / 100) ? Целесообразно ли использовать в вычислениях с финансовыми величинами число с плавающей точкой, которое отражает проценты? Если нет, то как лучше это осуществить?

Comment: Процент может иметь форму 0.00

Comment: а в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Целесообразно ли использовать в вычислениях с финансовыми величинами число с плавающей точкой, которое отражает проценты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там же написано: "Типы float и double не подходят для денежных расчётов,".

Правильный путь решения задачи заключается в том, чтобы применять для денежных расчётов
типы BigDecimal, int или long.  (эффектив джава, стр. 304)

Comment: Если ли путь осуществить это без использования функционала BigDecimal?

Comment: А в чем проблема использования его? Если вы не придерживаетесь рекомендаций, то какие проблемы. Идея проста не использовать порядок мантиссу в точных расчетах

Comment: считайте все в центах и держите все в Long. только аккуратнее с делением все остальное всегда целое